# Programmatically generate JavaDoc files

Tags: java, javadoc

Is it possible to programmatically generate JavaDoc files by passing in a class? If so how?

Comment: what ide are you are using? do you want a software that generates on the fly with each compilation? this is too short to be a valid question

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios, I am creating a JUnit reporting framework and I want it to also generate javadocs for the implementing test classes and possibly link the report HTML files with the javadoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaDoc needs access to the source. Once you compile, the comments are gone.

Comment: and if he wanted to run javadoc from a program on the source, he could check the faq - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#runfromwithin

Answer (score 0):

Your question only makes sense if you are also generating source code at runtime. Otherwise the same toolchain that compiles the source code can generate the Javadoc.